# OpenGL draw a rectangle filling window

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, glm-math, frustum

I'm trying to understand the OpenGL MVP matrices, and as an exercice I'd like to draw a rectangle filling my window, using the matrices. I thought I would easily find a tutorial for that, but all those I found simply seem to put random values in their MVP matrices setup.

Say my rectangle has these coordinates:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // Top-left
     1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // Top-right
     1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, // Bottom-right
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, // Bottom-left
};
```

Here are my 2 triangles:

```
GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};
```

If I draw the rectangle with identity MVP matrices, it fills the screen as expected. Now I want to use a frustum. Here are its settings:

```
float m_fov = 45.0f;
float m_width = 3840;
float m_height = 2160;
float m_zNear = 0.1f;
float m_zFar = 100.0f;
```

From this I can compute the width / height of my window at z-near & z-far:

```
float zNearHeight = tan(m_fov) * m_zNear * 2;
float zNearWidth = zNearHeight * m_width / m_height;
float zFarHeight = tan(m_fov) * m_zFar * 2;
float zFarWidth = zFarHeight * m_width / m_height;
```

Now I can create my view & projection matrices:

```
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(m_fov), m_width / m_height, m_zNear, m_zFar);
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -m_zNear));
```

I'd now expect this to make my rectangle to fill the window:

```
glm::mat4 identity = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 rectangleModelMatrix = glm::scale(identity, glm::vec3(zNearWidth, zNearHeight, 1));
```

But doing so, my rectangle is way too big. What did I miss?

---

SOLUTION: as @Rabbid76 pointed out, the problem was the computation of my z-near size, which must be:

```
float m_zNearHeight = tan(glm::radians(m_fov) / 2.0f) * m_zNear * 2.0f;
float m_zNearWidth = m_zNearHeight * m_width / m_height;
```

Also, I now need to specify my object coordinates in normalized view space ([-0.5, 0.5]) rather than device space ([-1, 1]). Thus my vertices must now be:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, // Top-left
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, // Top-right
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, // Bottom-left
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projected height, of an object on a plan which is parallel to the xy plane of the view is

```
h' = h * tan(m_fov / 2) / -z
```

[image]

where `h` is the height of the object on the plane, `-z` is the depth and `m_fov` is the field of view angle.

In your case `m_fov` is 45° and `-z` is -0.1 (`-m_zNear`), thus `tan(m_fov / 2) / z` is ~4,142.
Since the height of the quad is 2, the projected height of the quad is ~8,282.

To create a quad which fits exactly in the viewport, use a filed of view angle of 90° and a distance to the object of 1, because `tan(90° / 2) / 1` is 1. e.g:

```cpp
float m_fov = 90.0f;
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(m_fov), m_width / m_height, m_zNear, m_zFar);
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
```

If `tan(m_fov / 2) == -z`, then an object with the bottom of -1 and the top of 1 fits into the viewport.
Because of the division by `z`, the projected size of on object on the viewport decrease linear by the distance to the camera.

Comment: Oh boy, I just forgot to divide my angle by 2 and convert it to radians... Using float m_zNearHeight = (float) tan(m_fov * M_PI / 180.0f / 2.0f) * m_zNear * 2.0f; nails it. Thanks for pointing my error! Still a last problem: I still have to scale my rectangle by 0.5 (or to create my vertices in [-0.5 .. 0.5] instead of [-1.0 .. 1.0] ). Isn't [-1.0 .. 1.0] OpenGL default coordinates range?

Comment: @TimAutin In your code you've a scale `lm::scale(identity, glm::vec3(zNearWidth, zNearHeight, 1))`

Comment: Yes, this is to resize my rectangle to the size of my z-near plane. But I still need to scale the rectangle by 0.5 to make it filling the window, or put 0.5 instead of each 1.0 in my vertices array

Comment: @TimAutin But the scale is worng `zNearHeight = tan(m_fov) * m_zNear * 2;`. - there is the factor 2. `tan(m_fov) * m_zNear * 2` scales an object with size 1, but an object from -1 to 1 has a size of 2.

Comment: I don't think my formula is wrong: `tan(m_fov/2) = 0.5 * zNearHeight / zNear`, which gives `zNearHeight = tan(m_fov) * m_zNear * 2;`

Comment: @TimAutin Yes for an object with size 1. But your object has a size of 2.

Comment: Yes ok, so once we use the MVP matrices coordinates must be in [ -0.5 .. 0.5 ], right?

Comment: @TimAutin No, that's up to your transformation. Coordinates in normalized device space are [-1, 1], but your coordinates are in view space, that is a different coordinate system. Anyway your scale is "wrong", because you do not consider that your objects is symmetrically to an horizontal axis. It has a bottom and a top, so you don't need the scale of 2. On the other hand it is correct, because it is just a matter of specification.

Comment: Mmh not sure I understood why it's wrong, but I understood why it's correct, so it seems all good :) . Thank you very much!